# Image cannot get parent attributes

Tags: javascript, html

*Sorry for formatting: typing from the phone.

Hello guys!

Help me please with a problem: embedded img inside div not changing it's width in respect to it's parent.

```
<div display="block" position="absolute" width="608.5px" height="480.5px" text-align="center" top="20%" left="50%">
    <img src="here_is_source" width="100%" height="auto">
</div>
```

So, I can't use CSS because I'm appending it using JS (element.appendChild), as well as creating properties of the element using element.setAttribute.
Thank you for suggestions, guys!

Comment: I see no reason for you not being able to use css. you can even add the css from js.

Comment: @Coffeeholic thanks, I'll browse for this solution

Comment: @Coffeeholic one problem is - I'm creating fabric-like function to return an element. So, I should paste an attribute inside function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set the props you are setting directly to a div. Use style, or insert a CSS style in the JS you describe.

Below solution solves your issue as stated, however also consider using

```
element.classList.add("my-class");
```

```
<div style="display:block;position:absolute; width:608.5px;height:480.5px;text-align:center;top:20%;left:50%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="100%" height="auto"/>
</div>
```